# C# Windows Forms how to get the ListView Items

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am trying to create a string with items from a ListView in C#(Windows Forms). I have two columns and over hundreds of three digit numbers in my ListView. The values indicate which X and Y axis my mouse was on. But as soon as I try to output the values in e.g. a text box, only the last X and Y values appear, the rest are ignored.
What I have tried:

```
listView1.Items[a].SubItems[0].Text
int.Parse(listView1.Items[a].SubItems[0].Text)
```

maybe someone has a suggestion

Comment: What is in `a` ?

Comment: You definitely need a loop that loops over **all** listview items. We can only guess that for some reason `a` points to this very last element.

Comment: So in principle insert a loop instead of the "a" for one column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use a loop for your items? It's not clear where `a` comes from. You might also want to use a loop for your subitems. 
you can loop through all items and subitems like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Count; k++)
    {
        string s = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[k].Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate over the items and subitems in this manner:

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Item: {item.Text}");

    foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem subitem in item.SubItems)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"\tSubitem:{subitem.Text}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help guys,
the only thing missing was the loop and this line `Value += Environment.NewLine +`

your suggestions both worked

```
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
            {
                Value += Environment.NewLine + item.Text;

                foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem subitem in item.SubItems)
                {
                    Value += Environment.NewLine + subitem.Text;
                }
            }
```

and

```
            for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Count; k++)
                {
                    Value += Environment.NewLine + listView1.Items[i].SubItems[k].Text;
                }
            }
```